# Eclipse shortcut key for replace special characters by unicode escape sequence

Tags: eclipse, character-encoding, keyboard-shortcuts, unicode-escapes

Is there a shortcut key in Ecplise that allows to replace an special character (accented) by its unicode escape sequence (\uXXXX)?

Comment: I was looking for a shortcut key, not a plugin. But, no problem, now it's upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/unicode-escape-eclipse/) with two text fields for simultaneous escaping to and from unicode.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use java editor templates (see *Eclipse Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates*) and add a template for each special character that you want to replace.
For example:

Name: ö
Context: Java
Automatically insert: true
Pattern: \u00F6

Now hit ctrl-space after an occurence of 'ö' in the source code, this will pop up a context menu allowing you to replace it with the unicode escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is.

The best I can suggest is to run your source files through the `native2ascii` from the command line.  (And then "Refresh" ... )

Comment: Yes, yesterday I've passed by all the shortcuts, using ctrl+shif+L. I decided to use UTF-8 in all files in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell if you are using Eclipse with Java - in case you **are** and **if** you have at some point installed `Windowbuilder` as well, you can use its automatic code generation to quickly replace all occurrences of special/accented characters within some text with their unicode representation.

Just create some dummy GUI object in `Design view` (e.g. `JLabel`), type the string into the `text` property and you'll get all special characters automatically unicode escaped after switching back to the `Source view`.

In case you are working in non-Java environment you might keep anoter instance of Eclipse opened - as a handy unicode-escaping-converter.

Comment: The plugin unicode-escape-eclipse suggested by Martin doesn't require two Eclipse instances.